# How to prioritise loading of one web part in SPFx?

Tags: spfx-webparts, react-webpart, carousel

I have a SharePoint modern page on which I have a couple of web parts installed. The web part on top is a carousel that needs to be rendered first. The problem I am facing is that when the page is loaded, all webparts load quickly and the carousel loads at the last which makes it a bad user Experience. How can I make sure that the carousel web part loads first.

Additional Information:
Jquery is loaded after a delay of 3 seconds to ensure that all css has been rendered first. Can it be causing the problem?

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
     SPComponentLoader.loadScript(url+'/Styles/js/owl.carousel.js');
   },3000);
```

Comment: Does your carousel depend on jQuery?

Comment: @CallumCrowley Yes, it does.